# Magnetic detector for electron beam

Tags: electrons, electromagnetic-induction, microscopy

I want to create a mathematical model for a magnetic electron beam detector.
It is composed by an air gap inductor with inductance $L$  and distance $d$.
An electron beam with Energy $E_b$ and number of emitted electrons/sec $n_e$ crossed the inductor. Assuming that the inductor has no external current->voltage changing over the time.

What should be the voltage and/or current produced in the inductor?

Could be a 10 keV electron beam detected ($max(v_L(t))>1mV)$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the setup to detect a magnetic field (a varying magnetic field), as it will generate some current into the solenoid (when passing along its axis).

In order to measure, or detect, electrons (or charged particles for that matter) you need more than that. Generally, they are detected by being deflected from the magnetic field generated by the solenoid (Lorentz force)- thus, you need current in it.
By shooting electrons through a simple, "inactive", solenoid you will not see anything (at least in your collinear geometry).

A different story is if the beam crosses with some angle the solenoid. In this case, the longitudinal component of the magnetic field generated by the electrons will be detected by the solenoid. As for the sensitivity, it depends on the components you'll use for building the solenoid - anything can be detected as long as your instruments are sensitive enough.

Comment: Just to take into account that the diameter of the inductor would be 5 to 10 micrometers. Still not enough to be detected?